# Why are my .php files failing to be interpreted as php?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine, putty

I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 w/ apache2 on an Oracle VM running linux. I have followed the following guides line by line to set these up as well as php 8.1:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtH9D2SqBqA
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-22-04

I have an example file I am trying to test: my_ip/test.php where my_ip is the ip address of my virtual machine.

The code in test.php is:

```
<?php
$x =2;
$y =2;
echo ($x + $y);
echo "<h1>This is a test.</h1>";
?>
```

This is being displayed onscreen @ my_ip/test.php:

This is a test."; ?>

My current interpretation is that this page is being parsed as an html file. I have done an hours worth of googling and tampering with config files but nothing worked, I ended up reverting all changes to config files so as not to prevent potential fixes provided here from working.

If it's relevant, I am accessing my linux vm server through putty.

On a side note, I have tried aliasing my server so that I can refer to it with a different address and not have to explicitly write my ip address but have failed. Can anyone point me in the direction of a guide that could help with this? I have tried following this guide line by line: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-22-04
however I am not able to successfully use http://your_domain. I simply get Server Not Found.

I tried following the aforementioned guides line by line, and was expecting my server's behavior to mimic that displayed in the guide's however my php files are not being executed properly. Also, I cannot refer to my server by its alias.

Comment: If you open developer console is the file being loaded by apache or from the file system?

Comment: The tutorial you linked only guides you through installing apache which is just a web server, it does not interpret PHP files on its own. For that, you need to install PHP. I'm sure DO has a guide for that too =)

Comment: @PsychoMantis I have already installed PHP 8.1 on the VM, should have mentioned that.

Comment: @user3783243 I'm getting a bug trying to run it in firefox so I ran it on chrome and checking dev console yields: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) favicon.ico:1. Also, Chrome is displaying my php file as plain text, that is: <?php

$x = 2;
$y = 2;

echo ($x + $y);

echo "Hello"
?> is printed to the screen. (i changed the php a bit incase the h1 tags were causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: Followed Ubuntu's PHP installation instructions for apache here https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/2a3819f0-ubuntu-server-guide-2023-02-19.pdf

I believe I did NOT install the apache php module, despite installing php 8.1.

Running this command:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

resolved the issue and I am able to run php files now.